# Change country name to abbreviation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm retrieving some XML-data containing countries among many other things and I would like to link the country name to its abbreviation in order to match them with famfamfam flags.

See the example below:

```
    $('Result',xml).each(function(i) {
        var $this = $(this),
        user = $this.attr("Username"),
        country = $this.attr("Country"),
```

So the variable country will fetch the country name, so how can I dynamically change the 247 potential countries to it's abbreviation.

Below is a part of the list of the abbreviations and the full country names:

```
>FI  FINLAND
>FJ  FIJI
>FK  FALKLAND ISLANDS (MALVINAS)
>FM  MICRONESIA, FEDERATED STATES OF
>FO  FAROE ISLANDS
>FR  FRANCE
>FX  FRANCE, METROPOLITAN
>GA  GABON
>GB  UNITED KINGDOM
>GE  GEORGIA
```

Comment: Where is your full abbreviations list?

Comment: How do you receive your XML? Are you able to change what is output in the XML?

Comment: "Retrieving some XML" from where?  Can the source of the XML put in the abbreviations in addition to the full name?

Comment: Full abbreviations list: http://pastebin.com/XE3hFRvQ I don't have access to the serverside, so I may not change what the XML-file may contain.

Comment: "GB  UNITED KINGDOM"? That'll probably offend people living in / from N. Ireland.

Comment: It's an ISO-standard http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to ask yourself the question whether or not the abbreviation is somehow stored in your xml-response. I assume it is not, in this case you would need to create an object in JavaScript like this:

```js
var countryCodes = {
   'NL' : 'Netherlands',
   'FR' : 'France'
   // and all the other countries
}
var inverseCountryCodes = {};
for(i in countryCodes) {
   inverseCountryCodes[countryCodes[i]] = i;
}
```

Note: this in fact means that you will have a huge piece of code creating the countryCodes-array, which is more or less a database. Please consider putting in in a seperate js-file, called countries.js or whatever, and include if as (on of) the first javascript-file.

Now you can simply translate from a countryCode to the real name and the other way around, i.e.

```js
countryCodes['NL']
```

will result in 'Netherlands' and

```js
inverseCountryCodes['France']
```

will result in 'FR'.

A better option would be to determine what the most stable representation for a country is, I think that would be a country code, as names have different values in different languages. This way you could consider returning (server side) the countryCode as xml.

Anyroad, good luck!

NOTICE:

I just found this: http://www.geonames.org/export/ws-overview.html

It's a nice list of webrequests you can do, to get geo info of all sorts. the countryInfo one seems to do exactly the opposite of what you want, but still it could help you. For example, this way you can get information on Germany. By letting the server respond with a code instead of the name, this might be just what you need!

http://api.geonames.org/countryInfoJSON?formatted=true&lang=it&country=DE&username=demo&style=full

If you will use this, don't forget to make your own api.geoname.org account, instead of using the demo-username ;)

Comment: Thanks Herbert, amazing how quick I got an answer. I think this is what I was looking for. I will look more into it tonight and if it works I'll check your answer as accepted. Once again thanks!

Comment: worked well... thanks! went with this solution: var shortCountryCode = countryCodes[country];